# Buiding ionic app with vuejs returns missing assets in adnroid studio

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, ionic-framework

I'm working on a Vue + Ionic project and I'm trying to run the app on android studio emulator. The app works in our browser if we try to serve it locally, but when I try to build it for android and run it in android-studio, it fails with:

```
2023-11-09 07:02:14.750  5069-5108  Capacitor               com.micurobene.micurobenelite        E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/appui/js/app.7104b3cb.js
2023-11-09 07:02:14.750  5069-5101  Capacitor               com.micurobene.micurobenelite        E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/appui/css/app.ff372929.css
2023-11-09 07:02:14.751  5069-5100  Capacitor               com.micurobene.micurobenelite        E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/appui/js/chunk-vendors.9f5e8edc.js
2023-11-09 07:02:14.751  5069-5100  Capacitor               com.micurobene.micurobenelite        E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/appui/js/app.7104b3cb.js
2023-11-09 07:02:14.752  5069-5101  Capacitor               com.micurobene.micurobenelite        E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/appui/css/app.ff372929.css
2023-11-09 07:02:14.752  5069-5108  Capacitor               com.micurobene.micurobenelite        E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/appui/js/chunk-vendors.9f5e8edc.js
2023-11-09 07:02:14.752  5069-5100  Capacitor               com.micurobene.micurobenelite        E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/appui/js/app.7104b3cb.js
2023-11-09 07:02:14.753  5069-5101  Capacitor               com.micurobene.micurobenelite        E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/appui/css/app.ff372929.css
2023-11-09 07:02:14.753  5069-5101  Capacitor               com.micurobene.micurobenelite        E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/appui/css/app.ff372929.css
2023-11-09 07:02:14.753  5069-5100  Capacitor               com.micurobene.micurobenelite        E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/appui/js/app.7104b3cb.js
2023-11-09 07:02:14.753  5069-5108  Capacitor               com.micurobene.micurobenelite        E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/appui/js/chunk-vendors.9f5e8edc.js
2023-11-09 07:02:14.754  5069-5108  Capacitor               com.micurobene.micurobenelite        E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/appui/js/chunk-vendors.9f5e8edc.js
```

this are the scripts from package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --dest ../public/appui --baseUrl=/appui/",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "ionic": "ionic build",
    "production": "vue-cli-service build --dest ../public/appui --publicPath=/appui/",
    "productionMobile": "vue-cli-service build --dest ../public/appui --publicPath=/",
    "stage": "vue-cli-service build --dest ../public/appui"
  },
```

This are the steps that I'm using:

1. `ionic build` to generate the `dist` folder
2. `ionic cap add android` to generate the android folder
3. `ionic cap copy android` to populate the android folder
4. `ionic cap open android` to open android studio
5. click on the "play" button to start the app

I think the problem is something with the paths, but I can't quite figure it out. I'm new in the whole Ionic + Vue world so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1 `ionic cap sync` 2 `ionic cap build android` . 2nd command will open android studio where you can generate APK.